# Accessing variables defined in external function from internal function

Tags: python, python-2.7, closures

Suppose I have the following function that returns a function:

```
def make_square_matrix_creator(dim):

    mat = np.zeros([dim, dim])

    def square_matrix_creator(value):
        mat += value
        return mat
    return square_matrix_creator
```

Now, this code doesn't work, because the internal function can't access `mat`.

```
f = make_square_matrix_creator(4)

f(3)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mat' referenced before assignment
```

I know there are a few ways to get around this; I can make `mat` global:

```
def make_square_matrix_creator(dim):

    global mat
    mat = np.zeros([dim, dim])

    def square_matrix_creator(value):
        global mat
        mat += value
        return mat
    return square_matrix_creator
```

It works, but this has all of the problems associated with making global objects within functions

I can pass mat as a default argument to the internal function;

```
def make_square_matrix_creator(dim):

    mat = np.zeros([dim, dim])

    def square_matrix_creator(value, mat=mat):
        mat += value
        return mat
    return square_matrix_creator
```

But when I try this out in my real-world example, I run into problems with mutable defaults. Are there other options for giving an internal function access to objects created in its parent function?

Comment: If you are using Python 3.x, you can look into [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-nonlocal_stmt) statement.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 - I'll edit my question

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7, you can use `[:]` to indicate in-place mutation in the nested function. Example -

```
def make_square_matrix_creator(dim):
    mat = np.zeros([dim, dim])
    def square_matrix_creator(value):
        mat[:] = mat + value
        return mat
    return square_matrix_creator
```

I tested this in Python 3.4 (Sadly, I don't have a Python 2.7 with numpy to test it out , I tested in Python 2.7 with normal lists and it works for normal lists) . Demo -

```
In [50]: def make_square_matrix_creator(dim):
   ....:         mat = np.zeros([dim, dim])
   ....:         def square_matrix_creator(value):
   ....:                 mat[:] = mat + value
   ....:                 return mat
   ....:         return square_matrix_creator
   ....:

In [53]: f = make_square_matrix_creator(4)

In [54]: f(3)
Out[54]:
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an alias.

```
# This class is a minimally working shim for the numpy object
# because I don't want to import the full numpy package.
class K(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.v = other

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.v += other

def outer(x):
    mat = K(x)
    def inner(y):
        alias = mat   # Create alias to mutable object.  alias is now modifiable
        alias += 1    # Modify alias to work around Python 2.x limitation.
        return mat
    return inner

>>> f = outer(5)
>>> res = f(1)
>>> res
<__main__.K at 0x102acb1d0>
>>> res.v
6
>>> f(1)
<__main__.K at 0x102acb1d0>
>>> res.v
7
```